# Partitioning in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I have no experience installing Ubuntu and need some help.

My laptop, a Lenovo z500, has a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD with 8GB of RAM.

When installing, which option should I use: “Erase Disk and install Ubuntu”, or “Other” (manual partitioning)?

My goal is to have the best performance. What is your suggestion to install on these two drives?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you want to install your operating system on the faster drive. If you install your OS on a slow drive you'll find it will severely bottleneck your machine, even if you have a very good CPU and plenty of RAM.

The decision to erase either disk is dependant on if you want to keep using windows or not. If your drive still has around 30-60+ GB of free space and you still want to be able to use your old operating system i'd recommend dual booting.

Comment: No I'm just going to install Linux but I don't know how and when to install it. (I'm not familiar with the structure of Linux folders).
Thanks for the more detailed guidance on this topic.
I would like to know how you are doing with this volume and type of hard drive for yourself.

Comment: I would recommend using rufus, it's a graphical windows program that allows you to burn an 'iso file' (the linux operating system) to a USB stick in such a way that you can boot from the stick. I'll provide a few useful links to help you get started, if you need any more info just ask; https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview ; https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Answer (score 1):

The Solid-State Disk (SSD) should have faster read and write times than the Hard Disk Drive (HDD). It is a smaller disk (as would be expected), but 128GB is plenty for installing an operating system such as Ubuntu.

If you do not want any other operating system installed in parallel with Ubuntu (a Dual Boot system), then using Erase Disk and install Ubuntu onto the 128GB SSD would result in a faster boot sequence than installing on the 1TB HDD. If that is the sort of performance you are looking for, then that should be pretty straight-forward.

The 1TB HDD could be mounted on a suitable directory as a data disk if you need to store lots of large datafiles (movies, large databases, etc.)

Without knowing what you want to use it for, it is hard to give detailed recommendations about "best performance". Do you do use programs that do lots of disk access? Lots of internet access? Lots of calculations in memory? Each of those use-cases has different requirements to give "best performance". I've tried to show what my assumptions are when providing options in this answer. I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
In general, I just need my operating system to run very fast and keep all of my data on a 1T hard drive, such as videos, photos, and more.
The laptop CPU is also a core i7.
On my SSD hard drive, I don't need anything other than my operating system and software.
Please guide us through the installation process to know what option I should use.
Can I choose which hard drive to install after selecting "Erase Disk and install Ubuntu"? Or does the installation process automatically?

Comment: From recollection, on the same screen where you select "Erase Disk", you can also select the storage device that you want to install the OS onto.

Comment: It may be worth noting here that there is another Stack Exchange community called "Ask Ubuntu", and as your question is specifically about Ubuntu, if you asked it there you would probably get more people willing and able to answer it.  - Also, the Ubuntu installer tells you before it does something irreversible. If you select Erase and Next, it will ask you if you are sure and give you a chance to go back instead and try something else.